# Can you use two DE within the same Ampscripting

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I have two different Data Extensions, one (let's call it A) has a primary key of Email Address, with an associated field of Preferred Store Number, and the second (B) has a primary key of Store Number, with fields of address, phone, hours associated with it.

Is it possible for me to lookup the store number associated with an email address from DE A within an email, but then in the body of the email, populate info from DE B?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  What scripting have you done so far?

Comment: To be honest Adam we haven't done any of this particular scripting yet, but trying to scope out a project. Just wanted to make sure it was a possible solution before truly diving in. Thanks!